# Can't link ipopt library (C++ on MacOS Mojave)

Tags: c++, macos, ipopt

I would like to use `ipopt` and `cppad` in my `C++` software on MacOS Mojave.

Compilation stops as shown below.

Why does it compile and the linker still fails.

> Can somebody help?

I tried this on `Xcode` and `CLion`. Both IDEs give me the same error. I also frequently reinstalled cppad and ipconfig using brew.

`include_paths` seem to work. I am able to include headers as follows:

```
#include <cppad/cppad.hpp>
#include <cppad/ipopt/solve.hpp>
```

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Ipopt::IpoptApplication::IpoptApplication(bool, bool)", referenced from:
      void CppAD::ipopt::solve<CppAD::vector<double>, FG_eval>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, CppAD::vector<double> const&, CppAD::vector<double> const&, CppAD::vector<double> const&, CppAD::vector<double> const&, CppAD::vector<double> const&, FG_eval&, CppAD::ipopt::solve_result<CppAD::vector<double> >&) in MPC.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Update: here the first half of content of `CMakeOutput.log` after changing to -v option:

```
The system is: Darwin - 18.6.0 - x86_64
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
0


Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "a.out"

The C compiler identification is AppleClang, found in "/Users/peter/CLionProjects/PilotSwoppz/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/3.14.3/CompilerIdC/a.out"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
0


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.out"

The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang, found in "/Users/peter/CLionProjects/PilotSwoppz/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/3.14.3/CompilerIdCXX/a.out"

Determining if the C compiler works passed with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/peter/CLionProjects/PilotSwoppz/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_9bbd5/fast 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_9bbd5.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_9bbd5.dir/build
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_9bbd5.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc   -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_9bbd5.dir/testCCompiler.c.o   -c /Users/peter/CLionProjects/PilotSwoppz/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
Linking C executable cmTC_9bbd5
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_9bbd5.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc   -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names   CMakeFiles/cmTC_9bbd5.dir/testCCompiler.c.o  -o cmTC_9bbd5 


Detecting C compiler ABI info compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/peter/CLionProjects/PilotSwoppz/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_9bf27/fast 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_9bf27.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_9bf27.dir/build
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_9bf27.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc   -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk   -v -Wl,-v -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_9bf27.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o   -c /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
clang: warning: -Wl,-v: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.14.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name CMakeCCompilerABI.c -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fno-strict-return -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-sdk-version=10.14 -target-cpu penryn -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 450.3 -v -coverage-notes-file /Users/peter/CLionProjects/PilotSwoppz/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles/cmTC_9bf27.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.gcno -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -Wno-atomic-implicit-seq-cst -Wno-framework-include-private-from-public -Wno-atimport-in-framework-header -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/peter/CLionProjects/PilotSwoppz/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.14.0 -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_9bf27.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -x c /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c
clang -cc1 version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4) default target x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
Linking C executable cmTC_9bf27
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_9bf27.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc   -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  -v -Wl,-v CMakeFiles/cmTC_9bf27.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o  -o cmTC_9bf27 
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.14.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -o cmTC_9bf27 -search_paths_first -headerpad_max_install_names -v CMakeFiles/cmTC_9bf27.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-450.3
BUILD 18:45:16 Apr  4 2019
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 arm64e arm64_32 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em
Library search paths:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib
Framework search paths:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/


Parsed C implicit include dir info from above output: rv=done
  found start of include info
  found start of implicit include info
    add: [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/include]
    add: [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include]
    add: [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include]
  end of search list found
  collapse include dir [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/include] ==> [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/include]
  collapse include dir [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include] ==> [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include]
  collapse include dir [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include] ==> [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include]
  implicit include dirs: [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/include;/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include;/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include]


Parsed C implicit link information from above output:
  link line regex: [^( *|.*[/\])(ld|CMAKE_LINK_STARTFILE-NOTFOUND|([^/\]+-)?ld|collect2)[^/\]*( |$)]
  ignore line: [Change Dir: /Users/peter/CLionProjects/PilotSwoppz/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp]
  ignore line: []
  ignore line: [Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_9bf27/fast ]
  ignore line: [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_9bf27.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_9bf27.dir/build]
  ignore line: [Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_9bf27.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o]
  ignore line: [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc   -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk   -v -Wl,-v -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_9bf27.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o   -c /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c]
  ignore line: [Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)]
  ignore line: [Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0]
  ignore line: [Thread model: posix]
  ignore line: [InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin]
  ignore line: [clang: warning: -Wl,-v: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]]
  ignore line: [ "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.14.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name CMakeCCompilerABI.c -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fno-strict-return -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-sdk-version=10.14 -target-cpu penryn -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 450.3 -v -coverage-notes-file /Users/peter/CLionProjects/PilotSwoppz/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles/cmTC_9bf27.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.gcno -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -Wno-atomic-implicit-seq-cst -Wno-framework-include-private-from-public -Wno-atimport-in-framework-header -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/peter/CLionProjects/PilotSwoppz/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.14.0 -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_9bf27.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -x c /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c]
  ignore line: [clang -cc1 version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4) default target x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0]
  ignore line: [ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/local/include"]
  ignore line: [ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/Library/Frameworks"]
  ignore line: [#include "..." search starts here:]
  ignore line: [#include <...> search starts here:]
  ignore line: [ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/include]
  ignore line: [ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include]
  ignore line: [ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include]
  ignore line: [ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)]
  ignore line: [End of search list.]
  ignore line: [Linking C executable cmTC_9bf27]
  ignore line: [/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_9bf27.dir/link.txt --verbose=1]
  ignore line: [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc   -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  -v -Wl,-v CMakeFiles/cmTC_9bf27.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o  -o cmTC_9bf27 ]
  ignore line: [Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)]
  ignore line: [Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0]
  ignore line: [Thread model: posix]
  ignore line: [InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin]
  link line: [ "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.14.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -o cmTC_9bf27 -search_paths_first -headerpad_max_install_names -v CMakeFiles/cmTC_9bf27.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a]
    arg [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld] ==> ignore
    arg [-demangle] ==> ignore
    arg [-lto_library] ==> ignore, skip following value
    arg [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib] ==> skip value of -lto_library
    arg [-dynamic] ==> ignore
    arg [-arch] ==> ignore
    arg [x86_64] ==> ignore
    arg [-macosx_version_min] ==> ignore
    arg [10.14.0] ==> ignore
    arg [-syslibroot] ==> ignore
    arg [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk] ==> ignore
    arg [-o] ==> ignore
    arg [cmTC_9bf27] ==> ignore
    arg [-search_paths_first] ==> ignore
    arg [-headerpad_max_install_names] ==> ignore
    arg [-v] ==> ignore
    arg [CMakeFiles/cmTC_9bf27.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o] ==> ignore
    arg [-lSystem] ==> lib [System]
    arg [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a] ==> lib [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a]
  Library search paths: [;/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib]
  Framework search paths: [;/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/]
  remove lib [System]
  remove lib [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a]
  collapse library dir [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib] ==> [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib]
  collapse framework dir [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/] ==> [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks]
  implicit libs: []
  implicit dirs: [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib]
  implicit fwks: [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks]




Detecting C [-std=c11] compiler features compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/peter/CLionProjects/PilotSwoppz/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_cd7fe/fast 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_cd7fe.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_cd7fe.dir/build
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_cd7fe.dir/feature_tests.c.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc   -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk   -std=c11 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_cd7fe.dir/feature_tests.c.o   -c /Users/peter/CLionProjects/PilotSwoppz/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/feature_tests.c
Linking C executable cmTC_cd7fe
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_cd7fe.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc   -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names   CMakeFiles/cmTC_cd7fe.dir/feature_tests.c.o  -o cmTC_cd7fe 


    Feature record: C_FEATURE:1c_function_prototypes
    Feature record: C_FEATURE:1c_restrict
    Feature record: C_FEATURE:1c_static_assert
    Feature record: C_FEATURE:1c_variadic_macros


Detecting C [-std=c99] compiler features compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/peter/CLionProjects/PilotSwoppz/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_5a439/fast 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_5a439.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_5a439.dir/build
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_5a439.dir/feature_tests.c.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc   -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk   -std=c99 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_5a439.dir/feature_tests.c.o   -c /Users/peter/CLionProjects/PilotSwoppz/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/feature_tests.c
Linking C executable cmTC_5a439
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_5a439.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc   -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names   CMakeFiles/cmTC_5a439.dir/feature_tests.c.o  -o cmTC_5a439 


    Feature record: C_FEATURE:1c_function_prototypes
    Feature record: C_FEATURE:1c_restrict
    Feature record: C_FEATURE:0c_static_assert
    Feature record: C_FEATURE:1c_variadic_macros


Detecting C [-std=c90] compiler features compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/peter/CLionProjects/PilotSwoppz/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_90b48/fast 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_90b48.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_90b48.dir/build
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_90b48.dir/feature_tests.c.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc   -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk   -std=c90 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_90b48.dir/feature_tests.c.o   -c /Users/peter/CLionProjects/PilotSwoppz/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/feature_tests.c
Linking C executable cmTC_90b48
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_90b48.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc   -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names   CMakeFiles/cmTC_90b48.dir/feature_tests.c.o  -o cmTC_90b48 


    Feature record: C_FEATURE:1c_function_prototypes
    Feature record: C_FEATURE:0c_restrict
    Feature record: C_FEATURE:0c_static_assert
    Feature record: C_FEATURE:0c_variadic_macros
Determining if the CXX compiler works passed with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/peter/CLionProjects/PilotSwoppz/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_072a4/fast 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_072a4.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_072a4.dir/build
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_072a4.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_072a4.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /Users/peter/CLionProjects/PilotSwoppz/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
Linking CXX executable cmTC_072a4
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_072a4.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names   CMakeFiles/cmTC_072a4.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o  -o cmTC_072a4 


Detecting CXX compiler ABI info compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/peter/CLionProjects/PilotSwoppz/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_5e307/fast 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e307.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e307.dir/build
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e307.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk   -v -Wl,-v -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e307.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -c /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
clang: warning: -Wl,-v: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.14.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fno-strict-return -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-sdk-version=10.14 -target-cpu penryn -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 450.3 -v -coverage-notes-file /Users/peter/CLionProjects/PilotSwoppz/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e307.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.gcno -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -stdlib=libc++ -Wno-atomic-implicit-seq-cst -Wno-framework-include-private-from-public -Wno-atimport-in-framework-header -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/peter/CLionProjects/PilotSwoppz/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.14.0 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e307.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -x c++ /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp
clang -cc1 version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4) default target x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
Linking CXX executable cmTC_5e307
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e307.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  -v -Wl,-v CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e307.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o  -o cmTC_5e307 
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: That symbol is supposed to be provided by the library. Are you **linking** to `ipopt` as well?

Comment: It sounds like linking either never happened, or failed. Judging by the error message, it might have failed. Have you tried running the command shown at the bottom for more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work as follows:

The problem occured, because I didn't properly include the ipopt library in CMakeLists.txt. I resolved the problem with the following Make configuration:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(ProjectName)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

include_directories(/usr/local/include)
link_directories(/usr/local/lib)

set(SOURCE_FILES unmanned.cpp mpc.cpp)

add_executable(ProjectName ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(ProjectName ipopt)
```